# Having trouble bootstrapping my title and having menu animation be seamless and functional

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have broken myself trying to solve these simple problems

1:having the text animation in the menu dissapear when you close it like it appears when you opem it

2:having the menu header text animation delayed to that is doesnt cross over with the menu box icon

3:having the image appear right next to the title

4:having the main type title be bootstrapped so that the title resizes for the screen size / mobile

5:having the contact button in the bottom show the tooltip when you hover over it in like they do for the other parts of the menu

6:having the contact part adjust to size of the screen and maintain fixed in the bottom

If you could please help me out or tell me what to do that would be gratly appreciated, thank you

this is also my first time asking a question on stack overflow so forgive me if I dont know what im doing

here is the codepen, the menu doesnt open in the pen for some reason but is you copy it into vs code it does

https://codepen.io/Jaidxb/pen/RwgXEJE

```
<p>its being really annoying when I put code so this will do</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check those updates that and tell me if this could help you:

```css
/* Google Font Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&family=Rubik:wght@700&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  background: #151516;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.sidebar.open{
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 1s linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name{
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar i{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list{
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 96%;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li .tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar li:hover .tooltip{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li .tooltip{
  display: none;
}

.sidebar li a{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #111111;
}

.sidebar li a:hover{
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name{
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 0.5s linear;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i{
  transition: all 1s ease;
  color: #000000;
}

.sidebar li i{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5%;
    left: 0;
    top: 90%;
}

.sidebar li.profile a:hover{
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile{
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img{
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}



.sidebar li.profile .tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar li.profile:hover .tooltip{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li.profile .tooltip{
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out{
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(25,25,25);
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-section p{
}

.home-section img{
}

.sidebar.open ~ .home-section{
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 10em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);   
}

.line-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;  
    width: 24em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 600%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);    
}

/* Animation */
.anim-typewriter{
  animation: typewriter 1s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both,
             blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter{
  from{width: 0;}
  to{width: 10em;}
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
  from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
  to{border-right-color: transparent;}
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/c/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Responsive Sidebar Menu  | CodingLab </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='icon'><img src="logo.png" height="30" width="auto"></i>
        <div class="logo_name">l PORTFOLIO l</div>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn" ></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
          <span class="links_name">01 : ABOUT ME</span>
        </a>
         <span class="tooltip">/ABOUT-ME</span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-cog' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">04 : SKILLS</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">/SKILLS</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-bulb' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">03 : PROJECTS</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">/PROJECTS</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">05 : ANALYTICAL</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">/ANALYTICAL</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-folder' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">06 : DUMP</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">/DUMP</span>
     </li>
     <li>

    <li class="profile">
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-envelope' ></i>
          <span class="links_name">07 : CONTACT</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">CONTACT</span>
    </li>
        
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section class="home-section">
    <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">HI, MY NAME IS JAI</p>
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/3b2/prague-conference-center-1056491.jpg" alt="hi" width="100" height="100"> 
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```